# How to create toolTip like Grammaly with only pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Once a text is selected, I want to show a tooltip at the bottom that can dysplay two buttons  and also the tooltip must be at the center of the selection.  I'm not sure how to implement the tooltip to show up after it is selected.I want to create something like Grammaly, I dont't want to use bootstrap, i want to implement this with only pure Js, or some kind of plugin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attach an listener to the mouseup event and check to see if anything has been selected. If there is a text selection, then you can do whatever you want with it, like query an API and append a DOM node for the tooltip information.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
// listen to the mouseup event
document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {  
    // check if there is highlighted text
    if(window.getSelection().toString().length){
       const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

       // create a tooltip with some content
       let tooltip = document.createElement("div");
       tooltip.className = "text-tooltip";
       tooltip.textContent = selectedText;
       // ...

       // inject the dynamic tooltip into the DOM
       document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
    } else {
       // if no selected text, remove the tooltip
       document.querySelector("text-tooltip").remove();
    }
}
```